# Storing Class Instances in a Python Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a treeview in my tkinter GUI. Everytime I create a new instance of my other class, a new item is inserted into the treeview.  How could I store the class instance in the treeview so that I can call a function on the instance when I click on it in the treeview?

Comment: You would need to store a reference from the tree view to the class, then generate a context menu with available functions for the class. Unless you have certain buttons that get enabled/disabled upon selection.

Comment: what do you mean a reference from the tree view?

Comment: Storing a reference like in a dictionary. Make the index the same as the text for the tree entry. Then bind an event to the tree.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.value = len(text) * 5


class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.root)
        self.construct()

    def construct(self):
        self.tree["columns"]=("one","two")
        self.tree.column("one", width=100 )
        self.tree.column("two", width=100)
        self.tree.heading("one", text="coulmn A")
        self.tree.heading("two", text="column B")

        self.tree.insert("" , 0,    text="Line 1", values=("1A","1b"))

        id2 = self.tree.insert("", 1, "dir2", text="Dir 2")
        self.tree.insert(id2, "end", "dir 2", text="sub dir 2", values=("2A","2B"))

        self.tree.insert("", 3, "dir3", text="Dir 3")
        self.tree.insert("dir3", 3, text="sub dir 3",values=("3A"," 3B"))
        self.tree.bind("<Double-1>", self.on_double_click)

        self.tree.pack()

        self.my_dict = {
            'Dir 2' : MyClass('Dir 2'),
            'Dir 3': MyClass('Dir 3'),
            'sub dir 2': MyClass('sub dir 2'),
            'sub dir 3': MyClass('sub dir 3')
            }

        self.root.mainloop()

    def on_double_click(self, event):
        item = self.tree.selection()[0]
        print(self.my_dict[self.tree.item(item,"text")])
        print(self.my_dict[self.tree.item(item,"text")].value)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App()
```

The `self.my_dict` stores a direct reference to the objects you are trying to call. When you double-click on an object, the `on_double_click` event is executed, where in this case, it prints the object reference and the object's `.value` attribute that gets instantiated on `__init__`.

This is the basis by which you can write what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: And when you add a new object, make sure to add it into the `dict` with the proper key.

Comment: Thank you! But how do I get the value that I should use as the key?